# ¿Cómo sé qué grupos se superponen en clustering para determinar el mejor número de cluster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster

Después de una agrupación/clustering descubrí que algunos grupos se superponen. Por lo tanto, trato de encontrar el número correcto de clusters. Sé cómo encontrar el número correcto de clusters con datos digitales superpuestos gracias a [sickit-fuzzy](https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/auto_examples/plot_cmeans.html). Sé como aggrupar datos categóricos con kmodes pero no sé cómo obtener la puntuación de precisión, ya que se puede tener un fuzzy partition coefficient con sickit fuzzy.

¿Cómo evaluar la pertinencia del número de agrupaciones de datos categoricales? ¿Cómo sé qué grupos se superponen?

Por ejemplo con esta dataframe:

```
ID    Question1    Sex    Age    City          Type     Group
1     yes          M      32     Casablanca    Urban    group1
2     yes          F      45     Ifrane        Rural    group2
3     no           F      22     Imlil         Rural    group2
...
```

La columna `Group` me da la clasificación inicial.

Intente lo siguiente:

```
for ncenters in range(5,13):
    km = KModes(n_clusters=ncenters, init='Huang', n_init=5, verbose=0)
    clusters = km.fit_predict(data) # I have to get the accuracy: 
                                    # the equivalent of the fuzzy partition coefficient for categorical data
    print(km.epoch_costs_) # I will select the one with the lowest cost
```

Me permite saber cuál es el número ideal de grupos, pero no saber quiénes son estos grupos y cuánto se solaparon mis antiguos grupos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar cada instancia generada en un arreglo y luego usar la que es mejor para ti.

```
km_all = []
for ncenters in range(5,13):
    km = KModes(n_clusters=ncenters, init='Huang', n_init=5, verbose=0)
    clusters = km.fit_predict(data) # I have to get the accuracy: 
                                    # the equivalent of the fuzzy partition coefficient for categorical data
    km_all.append(km)
    print(km.epoch_costs_) # I will select the one with the lowest cost
```

Así podrás conservar las instancias si quisieras compararlas con más detalle.